# TensorFlow TFRecords load images sequentially

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having problems loading in images one by one after converting my own sets of images to a TFRecords file. At both train and test time they are loaded, in a random order, which for training is great, but for testing I require that the images come one by one.

**Conversion of own 2D gray scale *.png images to TFRecords**

I've converted my images to TFRecords by using [build_image_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py), and it seems to work just fine :)

**Reading in the TFRecords file**

To read in the images from the TFRecords file I use the following piece of code

```
def getImage(filename):
    # convert filenames to a queue for an input pipeline.
    filenameQ = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=None)

    # object to read records
    recordReader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    # read the full set of features for a single example
    key, fullExample = recordReader.read(filenameQ)

    # parse the full example into its' component features.
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        fullExample,
        features={
            'image/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/colorspace': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
            'image/channels':  tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/class/text': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
            'image/format': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
            'image/filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
            'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value='')
        })

# now we are going to manipulate the label and image features
label = features['image/class/label']
image_buffer = features['image/encoded']

# Decode the jpeg
with tf.name_scope('decode_jpeg', [image_buffer], None):
    # decode
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)

    # and convert to single precision data type
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)

# cast image into a single array, where each element corresponds to the greyscale
# value of a single pixel.
image = tf.reshape(tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image), [101 * 201])

# re-define label as a "one-hot" vector
label = tf.pack(tf.one_hot(label - 1, 4))

return label, image


# associate the "label" and "image" objects with the corresponding features read from
# a single example in the training data file
label, image = getImage("../image-to-tfrecords/train-00000-of-00001")

# associate the "label_batch" and "image_batch" objects with a randomly selected batch---
# of labels and images respectively
imageBatch, labelBatch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [image, label], batch_size=100,
    capacity=2000,
    min_after_dequeue=1000)
```

**Using the image to predict**

Then I load my saved model and its weights, predict_op, etc. and evaluate the prediction operation by:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(1):
        batch_xs = sess.run(image)
        batch_xs = np.reshape(batch_xs, (-1, self.img_w * self.img_h))
        prediction = sess.run([predict_op], feed_dict={x: batch_xs})
```

Where `image` is the return from the `getImage` function.

**Directory Structure of Images To TFRecords (just for ref)**

```
├── train
|   ├── chef
|       ├── data0.png
|       ├── ...
|       └── data5467.png
|   ├── chicken
|       ├── data0.png
|       ├── ...
|       └── data2098.png
|   ├── parasaurolophus
|       ├── data0.png
|       ├── ...
|       └── data2977.png
|   └── Trex
|       ├── data0.png
|       ├── ...
|       └── data2841.png
├── validation
|   ├── ...
├── build_image_data.py
└── labels.txt
```

**Update**

I've tried to print the filenames of the images received by the getImage function, and it is getting the images in random order from the TFRecords file.

1st run:

```
[output]:
data4918.png
data4984.png
data1144.png
data2186.png
data138.png
data573.png
data2590.png
data392.png
data846.png
data3222.png
```

2nd run:

```
[output]:
data5212.png
data1144.png
data3588.png
data4054.png
data2938.png
data3396.png
data4711.png
data3222.png
data5003.png
data1298.png
```

Shouldn't it read the images in the same order every time??

Comment: I don't understand what is the actual problem you're seeing. As far as I can tell your prediction code should work on one image at a time.

Comment: And it does only take one image at a time, however that image is random. I require that the first time I call getImage it should return: train/chef/data0.png and the next time train/chef/data1.png. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Sort the file names before putting them in the queue?

Comment: Yeah, that is also where I'm getting at. Could you please provide an example of how to create a tfrecords file with a sorted file name queue?

Comment: Instead of making a string producer with `[filename]` in it, make one with `sorted(filenames)` in it, and then use `tf.train.batch` instead of `shuffle_batch`

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Thanks, I've chosen to sort the data at the time of converting it to TFRecords, and that works great. However when I read in the data now, it reads in this order: [chef1.png, chef5.png, chef9.png, chef13.png, ...], i.e. skips 3 elements every time... Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you have more than one reader thread / more than one op dequeueing files from the file reader?

Comment: I don't think so, because when it loops around it (in the 2nd run through the dataset) takes  [chef2.png, chef6.png, chef10.png, chef14.png, ...].

Comment: It really does sound like you have more than one queue runner enqueueing file names or more than one dequeueing. Can you inspect your graphdef and your queue runners collection to make sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary solution I've created the following function, reading raw png images, without the use of TFRecords.

However it **must** be possible to do this with TFRecords! Please provide an answer if you have any ideas!

```
def readImage(filenames):
    filenameQ = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=False)

    reader = tf.WholeFileReader() # Magic function
    key, value = reader.read(filenameQ)

    image = tf.image.decode_png(value)
    image.set_shape([101, 201, 1])
    return image

image = readImage([("../image-to-tfrecords/train/parasaurolophus/data%d.png" % i) for i in range(1000)])
```