# Reading Multiple Images One at a Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have multiple images stored at my desktop that need to be processed one at a time by Tensorflow. My problem is that I don't know how to create a loop to accomplish the individual reading and processing of images.

I found on this site the code that enables the reading of multiple images stored locally. I placed the code where I thought I would work but it didn't.
The results obtained by the code below, out of thirty images only the first two were shown. Sorry about the formatting. Not an expert. I think the loop shouldn't be placed there as a whole and the indentation has to do something with the bad results. Any tips will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

```
...code

from PIL import Image
import os, sys

path = 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Images\\'

dirs = os.listdir( path )


....Code


if __name__ == '__main__':

    ...code

 for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
 loadedImage = path + item


 parser.add_argument('--image', type=str, default='loadedImage')


   ....code

    for i, single_3d in enumerate(pose_3d):
           plot_pose(single_3d)

    pass
```

I switched the above code to and it worked. However, my images are nor displayed sequentially. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?:

This is the code:

```
import argparse
import logging
import time
import os
import ast
import common
import cv2
import numpy as np
from estimator import TfPoseEstimator
from networks import get_graph_path, model_wh

import sys
from PIL import Image
path = 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\data\\'
dirs = os.listdir(path)
dirs.sort()
from lifting.prob_model import Prob3dPose
from lifting.draw import plot_pose

logger = logging.getLogger('TfPoseEstimator')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] [%(name)s] [%(levelname)s] % 
(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir('..')    
    for item in dirs:        
    im = Image.open(path+item)        
    f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)        
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='tf-pose-estimation run')    
    nameimage = f + e   
    print(nameimage)
    parser.add_argument('--image', type=str, default = nameimage)       
    parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, 
    default='mobilenet_thin_432x368', help='cmu_640x480 / cmu_640x360 / 
    mobilenet_thin_432x368')
    parser.add_argument('--scales', type=str, default='[1.0, (1.1, 0.05)]', help='for multiple scales, eg. [1.0, (1.1, 0.05)]')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    scales = ast.literal_eval(args.scales)
    w, h = model_wh(args.model)
    e = TfPoseEstimator(get_graph_path(args.model), target_size=(w, h))
    image = common.read_imgfile(args.image, None, None)
    t = time.time()
    humans = e.inference(image, scales=[None])
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    logger.info('inference image: %s in %.4f seconds.' % (args.image, elapsed))
    image = cv2.imread(args.image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    image = TfPoseEstimator.draw_humans(image, humans, imgcopy=False)
    cv2.imshow('tf-pose-estimation result', image)
    cv2.waitKey()

    logger.info('3d lifting initialization.')
    poseLifting = Prob3dPose('./src/lifting/models/prob_model_params.mat')
    image_h, image_w = image.shape[:2]
    standard_w = 640
    standard_h = 480
    pose_2d_mpiis = []
    visibilities = []
    for human in humans:
        pose_2d_mpii, visibility = common.MPIIPart.from_coco(human)
        pose_2d_mpiis.append([(int(x * standard_w + 0.5), int(y * standard_h + 0.5)) for x, y in pose_2d_mpii])
        visibilities.append(visibility)
        pose_2d_mpiis = np.array(pose_2d_mpiis)
        visibilities = np.array(visibilities)
        transformed_pose2d, weights = poseLifting.transform_joints(pose_2d_mpiis, visibilities)
        pose_3d = poseLifting.compute_3d(transformed_pose2d, weights)
        pose_3dqt = np.array(pose_3d[0]).transpose()

        for point in pose_3dqt:
            #my points print(point)
            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    a = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
    a.set_title('Result')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    a = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
    tmp = np.amax(e.heatMat, axis=2)
    plt.imshow(tmp, cmap=plt.cm.gray, alpha=0.5)
    plt.colorbar()
    tmp2 = e.pafMat.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    tmp2_odd = np.amax(np.absolute(tmp2[::2, :, :]), axis=0)
    tmp2_even = np.amax(np.absolute(tmp2[1::2, :, :]), axis=0)
    a = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
    a.set_title('Vectormap-x')
    plt.imshow(tmp2_odd, cmap=plt.cm.gray, alpha=0.5)
    plt.colorbar()
    a = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)
    a.set_title('Vectormap-y')
    plt.imshow(tmp2_even, cmap=plt.cm.gray, alpha=0.5)
    plt.colorbar()
    for i, single_3d in enumerate(pose_3d):
        plot_pose(single_3d)
        plt.show()
    pass
```

[Image 1 Jumps to image 10.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEpYg.png)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713034/tensorflow-tfrecords-load-images-sequentially).

Comment: By placing the statements on the right place,I managed to fix the problem I had. However, I run into the same problem like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713034/tensorflow-tfrecords-load-images-sequentially) . My jpg pictures are stored sequentially pic0,pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic20,pic30,pic100 but my code displays the images pic0,pic1,pic100,pic2,pic20,pic3,pic30.... How do I avoid that.?

Comment: If i understood correctly, adapting the line below will display the images sequentially . However, how do I find the total number of images stored on my directory. ?  image = readImage([("../image-to-tfrecords/train/parasaurolophus/data%d.png" % i) for i in range(1000)]

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713034/tensorflow-tfrecords-load-images-sequentially) from this question may provide some example how to read the image in the folder.

> My jpg pictures are stored sequentially pic0,pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic20,pic30,pic100 but my code displays the images pic0,pic1,pic100,pic2,pic20,pic3,pic30.... How do I avoid that.?

The issue is with the way the name in the image dataset, and additionally with the sorting step you add after reading the directory list. My suggestion is to rename the file image to have zero leading (example pic000, pic001, .., pic010, pic011, ..).

To rename the files (given your image names), a minimal example:

```
import os
s1 = os.listdir('.')
for  s in s1:
    if ".jpg" not in s:
        continue
    if len(s)==8: # handle pic1.jpg pic2.jpg
        #print(s[:-5] + '00' + s[3] + '.jpg')
        os.rename(s, s[:-5] + '00' + s[3] + '.jpg')
    elif len(s)==9: # handle pic10.jpg pic11.jpg
        os.rename(s, s[:-6] + '0' + s[3:5] + '.jpg')
```